# How to auto wrap the runtime output of R in TextMate R Bundle?

Tags: r, textmate

I would like to see the output be auto wrapped, otherwise long comments would exceed the line width and result in extra horizontal scroll bar in the runtime output window.

I know I can achieve that in the official R GUI, but in the TextMate Bundle I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a View/SoftWrap option. Is that what you are seeking?

Comment: NO, the view/softwrap only works for source code. I am referring to the runtime.

Comment: Hmmm. If you are referring to the console output, that is controlled by R's `options(width=<nn>)`.